# Is it possible to transform sublime text or emacs to something like bpython?

Tags: software-recommendation, python, emacs, sublime-text

I'm using sublime text 3 and I like it a lot, but maybe a bit more love for bpython. It detects what libraries are installed and has autocompletion for codes that weren't previously written in the text, if you ever used bpython you know what I mean.

But sublime is better overall, sometimes i use bpython because i can't remember all the functions that a certain library has by default and bpython autocompletes it. Is that possible in sublime?

A plugin that detects what python libraries you have installed, either on the PC or in a virtualenv and predicts the name of the function you're calling based on that.

If it's not possible in sublime, what about emacs? I know quite a bit emacs so I can use it instead.

Comment: You can consider asking an emacs-specific version at [emacs.se], where I presume the Emacs clergy are active.

Comment: @muru there's an emacs.se? really? really? se is growing and i cant keep up with betas! will do so

Comment: @muru done, i'll leave this here, i want to know if it's possible in sublime too, if it's possible in both then I'll use the one i like the most http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/6012/is-it-possible-to-transform-emacs-to-something-like-bpython